# Pandas column with a mixture of strings and lists. How to isolate just the list items?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Ideally I am trying to use np.where to do some conditional formatting based on if the values within a column are a string or a list.

This is my sample data set:

```
Out[101]: 

     CRM Opportunities Opportunity Name

3    [Sestina Bio, LLC , Austria , 1 EE]
4      EnviroPower Renewable: 2020-06-09
5       [Stimwave , Belgium, UK , 6 EEs]
```

There are a lot more so I don't want to have to pass the string to a list and check via that method. Ideally I want to isolate either all the ones that are a list or string.

I appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

a simple string method would be to use `str.startswith` and `str.endswith`

```
l1 = df['CRM Opportunities Opportunity Name'].str.startswith('[')
l2 = df['CRM Opportunities Opportunity Name'].str.endswith(']')

df[(l1) & (l2)]

    CRM Opportunities Opportunity Name
0  [Sestina Bio, LLC , Austria , 1 EE]
2     [Stimwave , Belgium, UK , 6 EEs]
```

or

```
np.where(l1 & l2, 'list','notalist')
array(['list', 'notalist', 'list'], dtype='<U8')
```

Comment: It's not working, no error when compiling. However,  it's not registering that the value within the column starts or ends with '[' or ']'. Any idea why that could be happening?

Comment: It's a list, when I do df['CRM Opportunities Opportunity Name'][0][0] I get "Sestina Bio" maybe I have to do a lambda with a for loop?

Comment: @Bigmoose70 do you have a dataframe or list? im confused

Comment: I have a dataframe but the value in each row in the column is a list other than a few rows that are strings and not lists.

Comment: if you have a mixed df then likely the objects will be strings and not true lists (if that makes sense) so you should be able to use str.methods, is there any additional while space in your column? try printing a few rows `df[your_col].head(5).tolist()` and see if there is any extra white space

Comment: I am not seeing white spaces: [['Consensys Software', 'Multiple ', '29 EEs'],
 ['CO-RO ', 'UK ', '4 EEs ', 'RB'],
 ['Aviation Capital ', 'Multiple ', '(Con Conv) ', 'RB'],
 ['Sestina Bio, LLC ', 'Austria ', '1 EE'],
 'EnviroPower Renewable: 2020-06-09']

Comment: This is what I am getting when I do startswith('[') all the rows that say NaN should be True

0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4     False
5       NaN